# ERROR! Unexpected Exception: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_vars'

Tags: python, ansible

Getting below error when I run ansible-playbook `ERROR! Unexpected Exception: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_vars'`

Below is the ansible version

```
MacBook-Pro:sponnusamy$ ansible --version
ansible 2.3.1.0
  config file = /Users/sponnusamy/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'library']
  python version = 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 18:31:42) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]
```

I tried to googled it, but couldn't find out the solution exact error. Please help me to solve this

Comment: We need to see the playbook code.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11304) out

Comment: 'load_vars' is not available in latest ansible version. I should have installed ansible 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'load_vars' is not available in latest ansible version. I should have installed ansible 1.9

Comment: Neither main Ansible repository, nor core/extras module repositories contain the string load_vars (neither current nor 1.9 branches). There are some traces of such a string in older versions, or uncommitted branches, though. Sorry, but in this form, it is a useless answer to a useless question.